Edge GraphQL endpoint is giving Unexpected Execution
In my current project setup, which includes Sitecore 10.3 deployed on XM Cloud and Next.js hosted on Vercel, I've encountered an issue with a component utilizing a GraphQL query. While the component performs as expected in my local development environment, deploying changes to XM Cloud results in receiving a status 200 response but with an accompanying error in the response data.
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 4,
                "column": 11
            }
        ],
        "path": [
            "datasource",
            "children"
        ]
    }
],
"data": {
    "datasource": {
        "children": null
    }
}

}
Reference

Please share any insights or experiences you have regarding similar issues.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

After submitting a support ticket to Sitecore, they explained that the issue likely stems from the Similar to Edge Endpoint / sc_apikey setup. There are separate Context ID versions for Preview and Live environments, which are essential for JSS queries and specified in the "\src\sxastarter\env" file under the variable "SITECORE_EDGE_CONTEXT_ID=".
To address this, I accessed the Deploy portal > Project > Details tab to retrieve the live Context ID. Then, I created a new variable in SITECORE_EDGE_CONTEXT_ID and updated the value accordingly. After rebuilding and redeploying, the issue was successfully resolved.

Please remove the "after" parameter as you are fetching the first 4 items. Also check the "endcursor" value first and apply the same in "after"
Edit:
The "after" value will not be same in preview and edge
For preview "after" is OA==
For edge "after" is eyJzZWFyY2hBZnRlciI6WzYwMCwiL3NpdGVjb3JlL2NvbnRlbnQvZGFydC96aXBsb2MvaG9tZS9zdXBwb3J0IiwiMTQ5RjQ1QzM0MjhENDc1MEEyMTk0OTgwODIxNzFCNEUiXSwiY291bnQiOjEwfQ==
Please find the below images for reference
Preview:

Edge:


I appreciate your input.  the logic is already set up. If you have access to both the preview and published GraphQL IDEs, could you please run the request query? and you will see the issue.

Modified the answer. The after value you are using is causing the issue in edge

Could you please take a moment to review the issue? It appears that everything functions correctly in the preview mode, but there's an issue when accessing the published page for the first time. Upon investigation, it seems that Sitecore is referring to the preview as 'Edge,' causing an incorrect endCursor. I've already initiated a ticket with Sitecore, and they've suggested some adjustments to be made in the SITECORE_EDGE_CONTEXT_ID. I'll be posting a detailed answer shortly to ensure that everyone can benefit from the solution.
